# Insufficient permissions when reading file metadata Python

Tags: python, google-oauth

I am trying to access the metadata of a file. I need this specifc filed:

"modifiedTime": "2019-01-31T15:46:44.118Z",

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221RtbvNMixSkhZcDxa3L3lTYQzUKZ1zaGGoCUrHMZ5cFM%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22modifiedTime%22%7D

I try it through the site and it works fine.

However when I try it in Python it returns 'Insufficient Permission'

```
credentials = get_credentials()
rangeName = sheet_name + "!" + range_name
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
result = service.files().get(fileId='1RtbvNMixSkhZcDxa3L3lTYQzUKZ1zaGGoCUrHMZ5cFM',fields='modifiedTime').execute()
#result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=rangeName).execute()
```

Inside the credentials the scope is set as:

"scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],

The code works perfectly fine for reading the SpreadSheet (if I change to 'sheets' 'v4', and change the scope and remove the comment on the last row).

What am I missing? Is there some permission that has to be set in google drive? Is it part of the credentials?

Comment: does the user of the token used have access to the worksheet?

Comment: Yes. It can read it through the sheets api. And the owner of the file has confirmed that the user is among the people with modify access to the drive folder. Is there another permission required somewhere?